# Facing Error Implementing CRUD operations using spfi pnpjs package

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, pnp, pnpjs

I was trying to implement CRUD Operations using spfi. So, I was following this PnpJS Blog to find solution to my problem: https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/sp/items/

So, they have imported spfi and assigned it to the variable sp.

For example: I am pasting a sample of code from the documentation to add item.

```
import { spfi } from "@pnp/sp";
import "@pnp/sp/webs";
import "@pnp/sp/lists";
import "@pnp/sp/items";
import { IItemAddResult } from "@pnp/sp/items";

const sp = spfi(...);

// add an item to the list
const iar: IItemAddResult = await sp.web.lists.getByTitle("My List").items.add({
  Title: "Title",
  Description: "Description"
});

console.log(iar);
```

So, my doubt is, `const sp = spfi(...)` what should I write in place of 3 dots inside spfi to make this functionality run.

Comment: Hi @Kshitij, does my below response help you in any way? If yes, Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) & [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you & it will help others with similar question in future.

Answer (score 3):

You have to provide the SPFx web part context to `spfi()` in your sample code.

For Example:

```
import { spfi, SPFx } from "@pnp/sp";

// ...

protected async onInit(): Promise<void> {
    await super.onInit();
    const sp: SPFI = spfi().using(SPFx(this.context));
}

// ...
```

This is explained in official documentation of PnP JS library at: [Getting Started - Using @pnp/sp spfi factory interface in SPFx](https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/getting-started/#using-pnpsp-spfi-factory-interface-in-spfx)

Answer (score 0):

I am sure you were able to figure out the missing piece of code. You need to write it as follows -

```
const sp : SPFI = spfi().using(SPFX(context);

//or if you need logging as well, you can use the following code -

const sp : SPFI = spfi().using(SPFX(context)).using(PNPLogging(LogLevel.Warning))
```

Note: please make sure that the datatype for sp is set as SPFI else intellisense won't work.